# Return only true or false (PHP)

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I have this PHP code which should return only either true or false after running multiple stored functions, but unfortunately it does not work as expected.
I firstly check the email validation and return true if valid and false if invalid, then i am doing the same for username.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

// Email is valid
if(checkmail($_POST['email'])) {
    $_SESSION['v_mail'] = $_POST['email'];
    $valid = true;} else { $valid=false; }

// username is valid
if(checkuser($_POST['username'],5,10)) {
    $_SESSION['v_username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $valid=true;} else { $valid=false; }

}
```

I need to return only False or True after checking both.
I know that it is very small trick but i could not get it.

Comment: Why check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`? If the `$_POST` superglobal is filled, it's always a POST request. Check for the existance of `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['username']` using [isset()](http://php.net/isset) instead. `isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['username'])`

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Can i add a name for the form, then i check if the form was submitted. 'if(isset(formname)) { }'

Comment: No, only something in the form that has the `name=""` attribute

Comment: As a sidetone: That's one of the most unreadable indentation I've ever seen. You should really get used to some more standard ways of using newlines and indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

// Email is valid
if(checkmail($_POST['email'])) {
    $_SESSION['v_mail'] = $_POST['email'];
    $valid = true;} else { $valid=false; }

// username is valid
if(checkuser($_POST['username'],5,10)) {
    $_SESSION['v_username'] = $_POST['username'];
    } else { $valid=false; } //and between the last $valid value

}
```

or again this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

// Email is valid
if(checkmail($_POST['email'])) {
    $_SESSION['v_mail'] = $_POST['email'];
    $valid = true;} else { 
 $valid=false; return} //exit from the function if valid is false

// username is valid
if(checkuser($_POST['username'],5,10)) {
    $_SESSION['v_username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $valid=true;} else { $valid=false; }

}
```

Comment: `false&&$valid` is always `false` and `true&&$valid` is always `$valid`.

Comment: Nice point @icktoofay, btw this is what he asked for so i edited to $valid=false and $valid.

Comment: I tried it and it worked like a charm. If i will add another checks, should i duplicate the username check as it is for the further checks and just leave the mail validation as it is ?

Comment: @AmrAli consider using the solution provided by Bogdan which is more clean. Btw, you just need to initally set $value to true and then modify it only if you need to set it to false :) after all if statments check it to see if its true or false

Comment: @Federico Ponzi i have another code to check the returned value of those if statements. But my issue was to return true or false after going through all if statements and this what really you provided me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(checkmail($_POST['email']) && checkuser($_POST['username'],5,10)) {
    $_SESSION['v_mail'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['v_username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $valid = true;
} else {
    $valid = false;
}
```

Sorry was tired missed part of the code, however I would approach this problem little bit differently:

```
$isMail = (checkmail($_POST['email'])) ? $_SESSION['v_mail'] = $_POST['email'] : false;
$isUser = (checkuser($_POST['username'],5,10)) ? $_SESSION['v_username'] = $_POST['username'] : false;
$valid = $isMail && $isUser;
```

Or move `$_SESSION` variables to `checkmail`, `checkuser` functions and then simply `$valid = checkmail($_POST['email']) && checkuser($_POST['username'],5,10)`

Comment: That's not equivalent as `$_SESSION['v_mail']` won't get set if `checkuser()` fails.